# sed: properly replace lines containing paths via bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to write a bash script that will do backup-based DUPLICATE database (Oracle) from Production to Development host. One of the steps is to take a copy of the Production database pfile, edit it properly and then power-up a new instance on another host. I am having difficulties to do the following on my bash script:

Production pfile: (single line taken as an example, all others are the same)

```
*.audit_file_dest='/u01/app/grid/admin/orcl11/adump'
```

Let's say that the above line should be changed completely to:

```
*.audit_file_dest='/u02/another/path'
```

I've had a look at the examples on StackOverflow, but I really can't understand them. Can someone please help me on that?

Many thanks in advance!

### EDIT: Thanks a lot guys. This worked out like a charm. Topic Answered.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please click "accept this answer...". You should see a tick next to the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

If it's exactly as you pasted in the question, you can use `sed` to substitute:

```
sed -i "s@audit_file_dest='/u01/app/grid/admin/orcl11/adump'@audit_file_dest='/u02/another/path'@" your_file
```

Comment: Far too often I forget you can pick any delimiter you'd like.

Comment: It's easy if you find yourself running into 
`sed -i "s/audit_file_dest='\/u01\/app\/grid\/admin\/orcl11\/adump'@audit_file_dest='\/u02\/another\/path'/"`

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to change the single line in your question, @leafei 's line works for you.

if you want to customize your "pfile", like: 
change

```
nameA='oldA'
nameB='oldB'
nameC='oldC'
```

to

```
nameA='newA'
nameB='oldB' #here perhaps you want to keep the old value
nameC='newC'
```

you could try this:

```
awk  'BEGIN{s="\x27";FS=OFS="="}{if($1=="nameA"){print $1,s"newA"s;next;} if($1=="nameC"){print $1,s"newC"s;next;}}1' pfile
```

**test**:

```
kent$  echo "nameA='oldA'
nameB='oldB'
nameC='oldC'"|awk  'BEGIN{s="\x27";FS=OFS="="}{if($1=="nameA"){print $1,s"newA"s;next;} if($1=="nameC"){print $1,s"newC"s;next;}}1'
nameA='newA'
nameB='oldB'
nameC='newC'
```